# Python Requests Post JSON formatting

Tags: json, python-requests

I'm using the requests library to make API calls with MailChimp. Unfortunately, requests seem to be formatting my data incorrectly.

This is a json.dumps() of my `arr`.

```
[{"body": "{\"email_address\": testing1@gmail.com, \"status\":\"subscribed\",\"merge_fields\": {\"FNAME\":first}}", "path": "lists/xxx/members", "method": "POST"}, {"body": "{\"email_address\": testing1@gmail.com, \"status\":\"subscribed\", \"merge_fields\": {\"FNAME\":first}}", "path": "lists/xxx/members", "method": "POST"}, {"body": "{\"email_address\": testing@gmail.com, \"status\":\"subscribed\", \"merge_fields\": {\"FNAME\":second}}", "path": "lists/xxx/members", "method": "POST"}, {"body": "{\"email_address\": testing@gmail.com, \"status\":\"subscribed\", \"merge_fields\": {\"FNAME\":second}}", "path": "lists/xxx/members", "method": "POST"}]
```

This is what requests submits it as using `json=arr`:

```
{"body": "{\\"email_address\\": testing1@gmail.com, \\"status\\":\\"subscribed\\", \\"merge_fields\\": {\\"FNAME\\":first}}", "path": "lists/xxx/members", "method": "POST"}, {"body": "{\\"email_address\\": testing1@gmail.com, \\"status\\":\\"subscribed\\", \\"merge_fields\\": {\\"FNAME\\":first}}", "path": "lists/xxx/members", "method": "POST"}, {"body": "{\\"email_address\\": testing@gmail.com, \\"status\\":\\"subscribed\\", \\"merge_fields\\": {\\"FNAME\\":second}}", "path": "lists/xxx/members", "method": "POST"}, {"body": "{\\"email_address\\": testing@gmail.com, \\"status\\":\\"subscribed\\", \\"merge_fields\\": {\\"FNAME\\":second}}", "path": "lists/xxx/members", "method": "POST"}]}'
```

I have tried using `data=json.dumps(arr)` as well but results in the same formatting. Any ideas as to why the formatting adds second \s ?

EDIT:

Here's the relevant code in the program: http://pastebin.com/Q0zjHxHP

Comment: Can you add the actual code?

Comment: I have included the code in a pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/Q0zjHxHP